# What are the differences between these two Maven resource definitions?

Tags: java, maven

Could somebody explain me the differences between these two resource definitions? Why the jar files are excluded but in the second resource included? I don't understand these two declarations:

```xml
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
                <exclude>myDummyPath/war/l10n/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
 </resources>
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why did you eliminate a correct tag and add a wrong one here? This is a `java` question, and the XML is incidental.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry, I was attempting to get the syntax highlighting to work - eventually hexafraction corrected it. Seems you need `language:` rather than `lang:` in the language hint.

Comment: @chrylis ah, that doesn't work. Seems without the `xml` tag the syntax highlighting is not being overly helpful.

Comment: off-topic, but jars defined under `src/main/resources` have no effect: the content of these jars don't end up on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The first difference is obviously the paths:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
    <exclude>myDummyPath/war/l10n/*.*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

And:

```
<includes>
    <include>**/*.jar</include>
</includes>
```

Obviously the first declaration excludes all `.jar` files and everything under `I10n`. The second path, on the other, includes *only* `.jar` files.

Next the first declaration enables filtering and the second disables it. In maven, filtering (by default) replaces all variable placeholders `${...}` with their values - for more information read [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

So in the first declaration, all resources except `.jar` files and localisation files, are filtered by maven - substitution in values for placeholders such as `${project.name}`.

In the second declaration, all `.jar` resources are copied over, without filtering.

Comment: what do you mean with copied over? I don´t understand this

Comment: Well, when a project is built files are copied from the source code (`/src/main/`) to the built artefact -  the `.jar` or `.war` or whatever. The is a standard build process - if you don't know this then maybe you need to read [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the different `filtering` settings. The author wants Maven to replace placeholders in some files (maybe config files) but not to break binary jar files.